# Equivalence of two state Markov chain and sampling via geometric distribution

Tags: python, simulation, markov-process, geometric-distribution

Let $\mathcal T = \{1,2,\ldots,T\}$ denote the set of points in time, $S = \{0,1\}$ the state space, $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathcal T} \in S^\mathcal T$ a time series, $\alpha = \mathbb P(X_{t+1} = 0 \mid X_t = 0) \in [0, 1]$ the stationary probability that the state remains $0$, given it was $0$ in the previous period, and $\beta = \mathbb P(X_{t+1} = 1 \mid X_t = 1) \in [0, 1]$ the stationary probability that the state remains $1$, given it was $1$ in the previous period, respectively. The transition matrix of the Markov chain is then given by
\begin{align}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 1-\alpha \newline
1-\beta & \beta
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Let $\mathcal I = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ denote an index set. Assume we've have generated $n$ time series $(X^i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ and let $\overline X(n) = \sum_{i \in \mathcal I}{X^i} / n$ denote the average time series.

I was thinking that we can generate $\overline X(n)$ via an alternative approach. Note the following: Given the state is $0$, the probability that it is going to be $1$ after $t$ periods is $f(t) = \alpha^{t-1}(1-\alpha)$. And given the state is $1$, the probability that it is going to be $0$ after $t$ periods is $g(t) = \beta^{t-1}(1-\beta)$. Now construct the time series $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in \mathcal T}$ as follows: Initialize $Y_0 \in S$. If $Y_0 = 0$, draw via $f(t)$ for how long it is going to stay $0$. Then draw via $g(t)$ for how long it its going to stay $1$ etc. until $t = T$. If $Y_0 = 1$ start with drawing from $g(t)$, then $f(t)$ etc. Generate $(Y^i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ time series and let $\overline Y(n) = \sum_{i \in \mathcal I}{Y^i} / n$ denote the average time series.

**Problem**

Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \overline X(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \overline Y(n)$ true?

**Python**

I implemented the idea in Python with $(\alpha, \beta, T, n) = (0.50, 0.75, 100, 10'000)$ and it seems that the two approaches are not equivalent. In the figure I plotted the average of $n = 10'000$ simulated time series. Is my logic flawed? Or is the implementation incorrect?

[image]

The code to produce the figure reads as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameter
a = 0.5  # Pr(X(t+1) = 0 | X(t) = 0)
b = 0.75  # Pr(X(t+1) = 1 | X(t) = 1)
P = np.array([[a, 1-a], [1-b, b]])  # transition matrix
n = 10000  # number of time series
tf = 100  # length of time series
X = np.zeros((n, tf), dtype=int)  # Storage Matrix
Y = np.zeros((n, tf), dtype=int)  # Storage Matrix

# Simulation
# Markov-chain
X[:, 0] = np.random.choice(2, n, p=[0.5, 0.5])  # initialize
for i in range(n):  # loop over time series
    for t in range(tf-1):  # loop over time within time series
        if X[i, t] == 0:
            X[i, t+1] = np.random.choice(2, 1, p=P[0, :])
        else:
            X[i, t+1] = np.random.choice(2, 1, p=P[1, :])

# average
X_ave = X.sum(axis=0) / n

# geometric distribution
Y[:, 0] = np.random.choice(2, n, p=[0.5, 0.5])  # initialize
for i in range(n):  # loop over time series
    t = 0
    while t < tf:  # loop over time within time series
        if Y[i, t] == 0:
            z = np.random.geometric(1-a)
            if t+z < tf:
                Y[i, t+1: t+z-1] = 0
                Y[i, t+z] = 1
                t = t+z
            else:
                Y[i, t: tf] = 0
                t = tf
        else:
            z = np.random.geometric(1-b)
            if t+z < tf:
                Y[i, t+1: t+z-1] = 1
                Y[i, t+z] = 0
                t = t+z
            else:
                Y[i, t: tf] = 1
                t = tf

# average
Y_ave = Y.sum(axis=0) / n


# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(tf), X_ave, label='Markov')
ax.plot(range(tf), Y_ave, label='geometric')
ax.set(xlabel='t', ylabel='X(t)/n, Y(t)/n')
plt.title(f'number of time series {n}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Edit I**
There was mistake in the Python code due to (in my opinion) confusing accessing. It needs to read `Y[i, t+1: t+z]` and `Y[i, t+1: tf+1]` instead of `Y[i, t+1: t+z-1]` and `Y[i, t+1: tf]`.

**Edit II**
There was another mistake. For `z=1` we would not repeat the state. It therefore needs to read `Y[i, t: t+z]` and `Y[i, t: tf+1]` instead of `Y[i, t+1: t+z]` and `Y[i, t+1: tf+1]`. We should further note that `Y[t]=Y[t: t+1]`.

[image]

Comment: Is it a known result? How would I show it formally? Concerning the coding error: yes, correct but it does not change anything as I overwrite 0 with 0 in the first case and 1 with 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

According to the [documentation for numpy.random.geometric](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.geometric.html),

> The geometric distribution models the number of trials that must be
> run in order to achieve success. It is therefore supported on the
> positive integers, k = 1, 2, ....

this means that `z-1` should used as the number of repetitions of the current state, before moving to the other state. I thus wonder at the use of `Y[i, t+1: t+z-1]` when `z=1` and at the replacement by `Y[i, t+1: t+z]` which seems to always include a repetition of the current state, while it should not when `z=1`.

---

[image]

Since the Markov chain is a sequence of `0` and `1`, as eg

`0100100010111010111001`

updating the Markov chain one position at a time or updating the uninterrupted blocks of `0` and `1` all at once are equivalent. As noted in the question, when at a state `0` at time t, the number of subsequent `0` till the next `1` is a indeed Geometric random variable $\mathcal Geo(1-\alpha)$ [when defined as taking values in $\mathbb N$, i.e. zero is a possible value]. Hence generating using Geometric batch lengths rather than going one time step at a time is equivalent from a probability perspective (if not producing the same output when implemented on a computer).

I ran both ways of simulating the Markov chain in R and did not spot any discrepancy in the ergodic convergence of the chain average to the stationary mean $\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\alpha+1-\beta}$ (equal to $1/3$ with the chosen values):

```
T=1e5
a=.5;b=.75
x=1:T
for(t in 2:T)
  x[t]=(runif(1)>ifelse(x[t-1],1-b,a))
plot(cumsum(x)/(1:T),type="l",col="gold")
t=1
while(t<=T){
  y=rgeom(1,ifelse(x[t],1-b,1-a)) #warnin: number of failures
  x[t:(t+y)]=x[t];x[t<-t+y+1]=!x[t]}
lines(cumsum(x[1:T])/(1:T),lty=2,col="indianred")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that you are doing the same. I think you are generating a 1 x 10000 time series, then sum over the elements within the array and divide by its current length. I, on the other hand, generate a 10000  x 100 matrix, sum over the rows and divide it by 10000 which leaves me with an 1 x 100 array. It's nice to see, however, that there seems to be some sort of equivalence between the two approachs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to $z=1$. I also corrected that.

Comment: The fundamental question is does it remove the observed bias?

Comment: Yes, it does I guess. I rerun the simulation with the modified code and added a new figure.